# getting struct pointer to give to substruct

Tags: c++

i am trying to get GameAPI pointer so

that my substruct test can use it.

Code:

```
struct GameAPI 
{
    static GameAPI* Ptr;

    GameAPI()
    {
        Ptr = this;
    }

    struct
    {
        void func()
        {
            printf("%p",&Ptr);
        }
    }test;
};
```

ERROR:
unresolved external symbol "public: static struct GameAPI * GameAPI::Ptr"

Comment: What is your specific question about C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ copy struct unresolved link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948548/c-copy-struct-unresolved-link)

Comment: Keep an eye on `printf("%p",&Ptr);`. The results may surprise you. Note: This looks dangerous. Perhaps you are headed in the direction of [a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301). Not that singleton can't also be dangerous, but this has [a lot of extra blow-up potential](https://ideone.com/VTp32o).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only declared `Ptr` but you forgot to define it outside the `GameAPI` definition.

Add:

```
GameAPI* GameAPI::Ptr = nullptr; // or another suitable value
```

Comment: thank you i misused static this made me realise that.